# Appropriate way to capture dates in variables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle12c

Oracle SQL*Plus (and so SQL Developer) doesn't support declaring variables as date ([Citation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm#SQPUG133)).

So I can select into a varchar, but it requires I convert to a string.  Then it's not really a date anymore and I can't do date arithmetic on it.

What is the appropriate way to work with date variables?  I'm using variables instead of declares at the start of a BEGIN/END because I need them available outside of the block to make selects easy to display.

```
clear screen;
variable someid number; 
variable somedate varchar;
exec :someid := 1234; 

Begin
select c.some_timestamp into :somedate from someschema.sometable c
where c.someid = :someid ;
end;
/

select :somedate from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `to_date` or `TO_TIMESTAMP` if you want to do arithmetic.

Apparently it is `SqlPlus` limitation. Below is an example:

```
variable my_date varchar2(30)

exec :my_date := '12-04-2017';

select * from mytable where date_col = to_date(:my_date,'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

Take a look here [Declare a variable of type DATE using var](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2939749100346967872)

Comment: "SqlPlus limitation", so I'm not using the SQL*Plus client(sorry for not mentioning), I'm using SQL Developer. Perhaps everything outside of a BEGIN/END block is considered "SqlPlus" even if you are not using that particular client? Can you clarify.  I'll try your solution out when I'm back at PC.

Comment: @AaronLS - most things that apply to SQL\*Plus also apply to SQL Developer. This certainly does.

Answer (score 0):

This does more or less the same thing:

```
declare
  somedate date;
Begin
  select c.some_timestamp into somedate 
  from someschema.sometable c
  where c.someid = &someid ;
  dbms_output.put_line(somedate);
end;
/
```

Obviously you have the need to enable SERVEROUTPUT before running the script but you gain the ability to work with `somedate` as a date without needing to cast it from a string all the time.

---

Ultimately it comes down to the details of what you're trying to do. I find it's increasingly rare that I work interactively with SQL*Plus scripts these days: I use an IDE worksheet to develop them and then some shell program executes them autonomously. You say you are using SQL Developer, so you're probably on the same journey.

Comment: Thanks.  One important point of what I'm trying to do "I'm using variables instead of declares at the start of a BEGIN/END because I need them available outside of the block to make selects easy to display."  Using dbms_output or cursors becomes tedious quickly.